# PHP get unique id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

With help from this forum I wrote the code:

```
<?php
 if ($_POST['action'] == "delete_admin") {
       echo json_encode(array("result"=>true));
       exit;
 }

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query9)) {
  $res = array(array("adm"=>$row['id']));

  foreach($res as $a) {
   echo'<div id="adAdmListItem">&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row['admin'].'
    <span id="adRemoveAdm">
     <span delete-admin="'.$a['adm'].'">[x]</span>
    </span>
   </div>
  }
 }
?>
```

And jquery:

```
$('[delete-admin]').on('click',function() {
    var remove = $(this).parents('div#adAdmListItem');
    var admin_id = $(this).val();

    $.post('index.php',{action: 'delete_admin', admin_id: admin_id},function(data) {
        remove.hide();

    },'json');
});
```

This functions work properly. When I click on the [x] the item of list (admin) will be hidden. But I need get an id of admin (where I clicked [x]). Received id I have to send to php by ajax or XMLHttpRequest. The problem is I can't get the admin id. (I tried set the unique id - required in while loop, but I can't get it by jquery).
It's easy with php but in this case the page will be reload, I wanna miss that.

Comment: `'<div id="adAdmListItem">`, `<span id="adRemoveAdm">` Ids have to be **unique**. Use a class instead.

Comment: Following what Andreas said, ID's are unique. Utilize classes or `data-*` attributes and go from there. Also, next time, post more code - including HTML :)

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood the code and the question you may try this:

```
var admin_id = $(this).attr('delete-admin');
```